# How to extract a specific part from a column value in SQL (Redshift platform)

Tags: sql, select, amazon-redshift

I have values in a column NAME:

```
PROD_UPI_FIIT_20180101_121017.TXT
REG_ART_TQ_FIIT_20180203_091215.TXT
STORES_OR_NIIT_20180809_121709.TXT
TIRES_UI_PO_NIIT_20180104_070901.TXT
```

I have to write a query in so that I can see values in 3 columns as shown below:

```
PROD_UPI_FIIT       20180101      121017
REG_ART_TQ_FIIT     20180203      091215
STORES_OR_NIIT      20180809      121709
TIRES_UI_PO_NIIT    20180104      070901
```

I use Redshift database.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at regular expressions?

Comment: I have not tried Reg Expression but a little complicated logic, which is working but I am looking for other alternatives

Comment: If you already have some logic, post that to your question. It shows what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not REDSHIFT user, but you should be able to accomplish it by using [SPLIT_PART()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html) function, or a combination of POSITION(), SUBSTRING() and maybe REVERSE().

```
SELECT split_part(text, '_', 1) + '_' 
       + split_part(text, '_', 2) + '_'
       + split_part(text, '_', 3) as field1,
       split_part(text, '_', 4) as field2,
       split_part(text, '_', 5) as field3
FROM your_table;
```

I've used T-SQL in this example, but REDSHIFT uses same functions, I've assumed date length = 8 and time length = 6.

> ```
> declare @text varchar(100) = 'PROD_UPI_FIIT_20180101_121017.TXT';
>
> select substring(@text, 0, len(@text) - 19) name,
>        substring(@text, len(@text) - 18, 8) date,
>        substring(@text, len(@text) - 9, 6) time
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> name          | date     | time  
> :------------ | :------- | :-----
> PROD_UPI_FIIT | 20180101 | 121017
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7b6881854703475ebbf57e6d107ff78e)*

Comment: Yes, right. Thank you. In my query I had used split_part but the query become big, so I was thinking of other alternatives..